# Why does the following code generate a runtime error?

Tags: javascript

Given an integer array with no duplicates. A maximum tree building on this array is defined as follow:

The root is the maximum number in the array.
The left subtree is the maximum tree constructed from left part subarray divided by the maximum number.
The right subtree is the maximum tree constructed from right part subarray divided by the maximum number.
Construct the maximum tree by the given array and output the root node of this tree.

```
Input: [3,2,1,6,0,5]
Output: return the tree root node representing the following tree:

      6
    /   \
   3     5
    \    / 
     2  0   
       \
        1
```

```js
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 */
function TreeNode(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = this.right = null;
}

/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
var constructMaximumBinaryTree = function(nums) {
  if (nums == null)
    return null;
  return helper(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
};

function helper(nums, low, high) {
  if (low > high) {
    return null;
  }
  let maxIndex = 0;
  for (let i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    if (nums[maxIndex] < nums[i]) {
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }
  let node = new TreeNode(nums[maxIndex]);
  node.left = helper(nums, 0, maxIndex - 1);
  node.right = helper(nums, maxIndex + 1, high);
  return node;
};

console.log(constructMaximumBinaryTree([3,2,1,6,0,5]));
```

Comment: What's the exact error and what debugging have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
let maxindex = 0;
```

You only care about the maximum element of the range from `low` to `high`. If `nums[0]` is higher than any of the elements in that range, you won't find it, and won't properly partition that subsequence. This leads to infinite recursion.

Change that to:

```
let maxindex = low;
```

so that it only compares to elements in the range. And you can start the `for` loop at `low+1`.

```js
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 */
function TreeNode(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.left = this.right = null;
}

/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {TreeNode}
 */
var constructMaximumBinaryTree = function(nums) {
  if (nums == null)
    return null;
  return helper(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
};

function helper(nums, low, high) {
  if (low > high) {
    return null;
  }
  let maxIndex = low;
  for (let i = low+1; i <= high; i++) {
    if (nums[maxIndex] < nums[i]) {
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }
  let node = new TreeNode(nums[maxIndex]);
  node.left = helper(nums, 0, maxIndex - 1);
  node.right = helper(nums, maxIndex + 1, high);
  return node;
};

console.log(constructMaximumBinaryTree([3,2,1,6,0,5]));
```